# Error: gdal-config not found while installing R dependent packages whereas gdal is installed

Tags: linux, r, installation, gdal

Please point out the point that I am missing:

**openSUSE 11.3**

---

```
xx@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/R> sudo R CMD INSTALL rgdal_0.7-12.tar.gz 
root's password:
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: gdal-config: gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... ./configure: line 1353: gdal-config: command not found
no
Error: gdal-config not found
The gdal-config script distributed with GDAL could not be found.
If you have not installed the GDAL libraries, you can
download the source from  http://www.gdal.org/
If you have installed the GDAL libraries, then make sure that
gdal-config is in your path. Try typing gdal-config at a
shell prompt and see if it runs. If not, use:
 --configure-args='--with-gdal-config=/usr/local/bin/gdal-config'
with appropriate values for your installation.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rgdal’
```

---

```
xx@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/R> whereis gdal-config
gdal-config: /usr/local/bin/gdal-config

xx@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/R> gdal-config 
Usage: gdal-config [OPTIONS]
Options:
 [--prefix[=DIR]]
 [--libs]
 [--dep-libs]
 [--cflags]
 [--datadir]
 [--version]
 [--ogr-enabled]
 [--formats]
 xx@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/R>
```

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
```

---

```
xx@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/R> gdal-config --version
1.9.0

xx@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/R> proj
Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012
usage: proj [ -beEfiIlormsStTvVwW [args] ] [ +opts[=arg] ] [ files ]
```

---

```
linux-y3pi:~ # $PATH
bash: /home/xx/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/bin/:/home/xx/qtsdk-2010.05/bin:/home/xx/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/bin:/home/xx/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/bin/:/home/xx/qtsdk-2010.05/bin:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/home/xx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

Comment: aha! `which gdal-config` returns `/usr/local/bin/gdal-config` but `sudo which gdal-config` returns `which: no gdal-config in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)`

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need the `-dev` package with headers and shared library links for **development** besides the normal package for **deployment**.  Two different use cases as far as the distro is concerned.

On my distribution:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ dpkg -l | grep gdal | cut -c-72
ii  libgdal1-1.7.0                                1.7.3-6ubuntu3        
ii  libgdal1-dev                                  1.7.3-6ubuntu3        
edd@max:/tmp$
```

and `R CMD INSTALL rgdal_0.7-8.tar.gz` works just fine as you would expect from a CRAN package given all the build-time checks at CRAN.

**Update late 2016:**   As @JoshO'Brien points out in the comment

> Minor update: Here in 2016, running Ubuntu 14.04.2, `libgdal1h` seems to
>   have replaced `libgdal1`(though `libgdal1-dev` is still needed). At least
>   I get an error to that effect when I attempted to `apt-get install libgdal1`

For Ubuntu 16.04 the corresponding line would be
`sudo apt-get install libgdal1i`

Such renaming of upstream libraries is common; something such as `apt-cache search libgdal` can help locate the current package names.  The **important** key though is that the "abstract" development package `libgdal-dev` is all that is needed to build as it pulls the "concrete" current run-time package (here: `libgdal1i`) in via a dependency.

Comment: Minor update: Here in 2016, running Ubuntu 14.04.2, `libgdal1h` seems to have replaced `libgdal1`(though `libgdal1-dev` is still needed). At least I get an error to that effect when I attempted to `apt-get install libgdal1`.

Comment: +1 for putting me in the correct general direction.  And since we are in 2018 and not everybody work on debian based systems,... on Arch linux the trick consists in  doing `# pacman -Syu gdal` to download the rasterizing library from `community/gdal`.

Comment: @BrianStamper Sure, but you realize the _answer is eight years old_ so what the (currently) correct set is can change over time.

Comment: I hope you understand that 2012 was 8 years ago. I hope you are to read how the answer was already edited in 2016 for Ubuntu 16.04, and how in 2018 another answer was added.  They key for you to understand here is the power of something like `apt-cache search libgdal` to _at any point in time_ find the _then-current_ name.  That is fundamentally more valuable than a cookie cutter answer you copy without understanding.  Because the cookies do get stale.

Answer (score 193):

**In Ubuntu 18.04**

I fixed this by `sudo apt install libgdal-dev`
Hope someone find this helpful. Some above answers seems to be outdated and lengthy.

**In earlier versions (which had apt-get)**

`sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev`

Comment: It works for me in Ubuntu 18.04 and R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15).

Comment: worked for me (Ubuntu 18.04; R 3.6.3). Didn't need to "sudo apt-get install libproj-dev" for installing rgdal.

Comment: Yes, same for me using debian-stretch

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04.4 and R 4.0.2. when trying to install sf package and get a similar error.

Comment: worked for me in Debian testing bullseye for `{rgdal}`

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 until I also installed (using apt) libudunits2-dev

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: On Fedora it is: `sudo dnf install gdal-devel`

Comment: Worked for me Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 39):

You can use **apt-file** package, to find which package contains the missing file you are looking for.

First install the **apt-file** using the command `apt-get install apt-file` 
Update **apt-file** using the command `apt-file update` 
 Now you can use **apt-file** to find the missing file.  `apt-file search gdal-config`

For my case, I got the same error when configuring grass-7.1 from svn. As shown below:

```
$ ./configure
...more...
checking whether to use GDAL... yes
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
              ...more....
./configure: 1: ./configure: /usr/bin/gdal-config: not found
./configure: 6093: test: =: unexpected operator
configure: error: *** Unable to locate GDAL library.
```

But, after looking for **gdal-config** file with **apt-file** as shown below, I was able to resolve the error, after installing the package **libgdal1-dev**

```
$ apt-file search gdal-config
```

Results

```
libgdal1-dev: /usr/bin/gdal-config
```

So I installed **libgdal1-dev**, as shown below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev
```

Comment: This fixed the this error, but I also had to do `sudo apt-get install libproj-dev` to install `rgdal`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation

Comment: I can confirm that `libproj-dev` is also needed. R returns `configure: error: proj_api.h not found...` otherwise as mentioned by @geneorama.

Comment: I confirm this, including the package in the comments, solved my problem for Ubuntu 16.04 and R 3.4.

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.10, R 3.6.2 I only had to `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev`, no need for `libproj-dev`. Note: it was `libgdal-dev` not `libgdal1-dev`.

Answer (score 18):

This happens because the configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
so we have to install necessary dependencies.

The packages libgdal-dev and libproj-dev are required:

`sudo apt-get install gdal-bin proj-bin libgdal-dev libproj-dev`

Then install rgdal by

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

Load rgdal by

```
library(rgdal)
```

Answer (score 17):

On **macOS**

`brew install gdal`

removed the error

> gdal-config not found

Comment: Just a tip for others, pay attention to the terminal output after running it, as there may be other things you need to do (I had to install something else before gdal would install, and I had to link it after installation - but brew let me know how to do this in the output)

Comment: I also had to brew install udunits geos proj then gdal

Comment: `arch -arm64 brew install gdal` may help at Apple M1 chips.

Answer (score 6):

Try this on CentOS 6

```
sudo yum install gdal gdal-python gdal-devel mapserver mapserver-python libxml2 libxml2-python python-lxml python-pip python-devel gcc
```

Comment: Unfortunately on my centos server sudo yum install gdal-devel fails with a long set of messages about processing dependencies and then a bunch of errors. They seem to involve centos 5 versions (eg gdal-1.8.0-4.el5.elgis.x86_64) but Im on centos 6.

Comment: do we really need all of those?  `sudo yum install gdal-devel` isn't enough?

Answer (score 4):

Read the reference manual.

> SystemRequirements for building from source: GDAL >= 1.6.0 library
>   from http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource and PROJ.4 (proj
>   >= 4.4.9) from http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/;

Answer (score 3):

My Mac Monterrey continued to complain even after `brew install gdal`.

The suggestion in [this github issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1949#issuecomment-1203825856) did the trick, though

```
install.packages("sf", type = "source", configure.args = 
'--with-gdal-lib=/opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/ 
--with-sqlite3-lib=/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib/ 
--with-gdal-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/gdal-config
--with-proj-share=/opt/homebrew/opt/proj/share/ 
--with-proj-lib=/opt/homebrew/opt/proj/lib 
--with-proj-include=/opt/homebrew/opt/proj/include/
--with-geos-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/bin/geos-config')
```

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurred today to me on a Linux CentOS 6.10 on which I do not have administration rights.

What I did:

a) Create a conda environment dedicated to  my R version

```
conda create --name MYR
```

b) Activate the environment

```
source activate MYR
```

c) Install R

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-base
```

d) Install libgdal

```
conda install -c conda-forge libgdal
```

This solved the problem for me. My R version was 4.1.3. I guess other versions should work.

Answer (score 0):

For manjora or archlinux, just try:
`yay -S gdal`