# rgdal package installation

Tags: r, maps

The issue here is not exactly how to plot maps through R, as I have found already a pretty nice example [here](http://rpsychologist.com/parsing-data-from-a-text-file-and-plotting-where-people-live-using-ggplot2-and-openstreetmaps/), but rather how to make it work. In fact, I am unable to load library `rgdal`:

```
library(rgdal)
Error in library(rgdal) : there is no package called ‘rgdal’
```

However, when I try to install the above package manually, I get the following error:

```
....
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/eualin/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘/home/eualin/Downloads/rgdal_0.8-5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any input welcome!

Comment: If under a debian-like system, try to install the `libproj-dev` package.

Comment: I do use debian. installation of `libproj-dev` didn't change anything (I think, it was already installed). `sudo port install proj` guves the following exception: `sudo: port: command not found` Any idea?

Comment: What command did you use to install your package ?

Comment: @juba: I used `sudo apt-get install libproj-dev`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to install rgdal... And what version of debian do you use ?

Comment: @juba With `sudo apt-get install rgdal` I get an `Unable to locate package rgdal` error.

Comment: Did you use `install.packages("rgdal")` ?

Comment: It works now, but seriously, I had tried all of them already, with no luck. Anyway, I'll mark your answers as correct.

Comment: To mark an answer as correct, you can check the green mark. And you don't have to upvote every comment I made :) Glad you solved your problem.

Comment: I cannot "install.packages("rgdal"). I get "package not available for R version 3.4.4

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I f you look at the [package page on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html), you will see the following :

> SystemRequirements: for building from source: GDAL >= 1.7.1 library
>   from http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource and PROJ.4 (proj >= 4.4.9) from http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/; GDAL OSX frameworks built by William Kyngesburye at http://www.kyngchaos.com/ may be used for
>   source installs on OSX.

As you seem to be under Linux, you always build package from source, so you will have to install the corresponding libraries on your system. If you are under Mint, Ubuntu or another Debian derivative, you can do :

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev libproj-dev
```

One tip that can be useful, still under a Debian based system, is to install the `apt-file` package and run :

```
$ sudo apt-file update
```

Then, when you get an error such as :

```
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
```

You can use the following command to find which package you must install to get the missing file :

```
$ apt-file search proj_api.h
libproj-dev: /usr/include/proj_api.h
```

Comment: Didn't quite work for me, running Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca built on Ubuntu 14.04 trusty-- `apt-file` wasn't working. I ended up removing `libproj-dev` and re-installing it due to some corruption issue & then installing `libgdal1`, `libgdal1-dev` and dependencies (version 1.11.2 in the official repository as of this writing, but I saw [version 2](http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.0.0/) here so a change may be on the horizon)

Comment: If you're in the future and not seeing libgdal*1*-dev, it might be because GDAL 2 is out and the package name has dropped the number so just `libgdal-dev`. Ubuntu 18.04 seems to be like this.

Comment: I have installed all dependencies, but I still got the `configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.` The `proj_api.h` is also found in the `/usr/include`. Any idea?

Answer (score 43):

If you use OS X with the [Homebrew package manager](http://brew.sh), and have R installed through the [homebrew-science tap](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science), you can install rgdal by first installing gdal.

```
brew install gdal
```

You may first want to list the options available before you run this in case you want something *fancy* like postgresql support.  To see the available options type

```
brew options gdal
```

then to be fancy you can type

```
brew install --with-postgresql gdal
```

after a while you should be good to go with dependencies, since **proj** including your needed **proj_api.h** are dependencies!  Unfortunately, rgdal still won't find pro_api.h right now since it isn't looking in /usr/local/include.  To fix this and other possible maladies with your rgdal installation, use the following ***R*** command to install rgdal:

```
  > install.packages('rgdal', type = "source", configure.args=c('--with-proj-include=/usr/local/include','--with-proj-lib=/usr/local/lib'))
```

This should be similar to what you would also need for [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) with the exception of the brew steps, and your libraries/headers are most likely under "/opt/local/lib" and "/opt/local/include" respectively.

***Note: to brew upgraders*** if you are using "--with-armadillo" as an option with gdal, and upgraded armadillo to 7 from 6.  You will have to recompile gdal before you upgrade/reinstall rgdal.

Comment: thanks. your method works on my machine after a few failures according to other solution posted.

Comment: God sent solution! I don't know how many hours I spent on this. Eeesh

Comment: Worked for me. Only other thing was that I needed to restart R after installing the `rgdal` package.

Answer (score 30):

On a Fedora 21 system using R-3.2.0, the following worked:

```
yum install gdal.x86_64 gdal-devel.x86_64 gdal-libs.x86_64
yum install proj.x86_64 proj-devel.x86_64
yum install proj-epsg.x86_64 proj-nad.x86_64
```

Obviously this was the result of repeated tries to get:

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

to work. You can probably do it all in one install.

Comment: Worked for me on Centos also.

Comment: I'm in Fedora 27 and R 3.4.3 and this answer is still working!

Answer (score 16):

On ubuntustudio 14.04 (same for all debian distros):

```
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev libgdal-dev
```

Then I could install package rgdal

```
R info:
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"

Linux info:
Linux francois-K53SV 3.13.0-34-lowlatency #60-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 13 16:15:18 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 15):

Here what i did on Centos7:

```
yum install gdal gdal-devel
yum install proj-devel
yum install proj-nad
yum install proj-epsg
```

Then simply

`install.packages("rgdal")`

Worked fine but it wasn't clear at all.

Comment: Just tested in a fresh Centos 7, I think you need `proj-devel` and not just `proj`.  Otherwise, we're getting `configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations`.  This is for rgdal 1.2-6.

Comment: I needed version > 2.0 to use the sf package.  These instructions worked for me, though they took a long time, be patient. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263495/how-to-install-gdal-on-centos-7-4

Comment: agree with @HenrikB, I needed `proj-devel` for same error. also may want to use `sudo yum install ...`

Comment: These days I have some edit permissions on SO, so I updated this answer to install `proj-devel` (not just `proj`)

Comment: In Fedora, this worked for me: ```dnf install gdal gdal-devel proj-devel proj-nad proj-epsg```.

Comment: On Fedora 34, `sudo dnf install gdal-devel proj-devel` seemed to work.

Answer (score 6):

For ubuntu 16.04 and R 3.5.1, this works quite fast:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal libgdal1-dev
```

Then;

```
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev
```

Finally in CRAN;

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

Answer (score 5):

In OSX, I download proj from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks and I run the following command in R.

```
install.packages('rgdal', type = "source", configure.args=c('--with-proj-include=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Headers', '--with-proj-lib=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/lib'))
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
install.packages('rgdal',repos="http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin")
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me in all the searching I've done.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac (OS.X Version10.12.6) users, This worked for me. 
First, go to command line and install *gdal* using >>  `brew install gdal`
Second, got to Rstuduio(R console) and install the package using `install.packages("rgdal")`

Answer (score 2):

For me  (Ubuntu 16.04, R 3.4.2), a mixture of the above solutions worked:

```
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev
```

Then simply installed `rgdal` from CRAN.

Comment: Thanks for providing this. I was able to get it working for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: That one eventually worked out for me using ubuntu 18.04. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked on my system was to compile PROJ4 from source as described [here](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu#Using_pre-compiled_dev_Packages_for_PROJ.4.2C_GEOS_and_GDAL) and then instal the rgdal package as

```
 install.packages("rgdal")
```

Answer (score 1):

For people in multi-user environments with multiple versions of proj installed (from source), the method I used was:

```
install.packages('rgdal',configure.args="--with-proj-include=/sw/proj/4.9.2/include --with-proj-lib=/sw/proj/4.9.2/lib")
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you need to `install libgdal-dev:`

$ `sudo apt install libgdal-dev`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still has issues on this, I got a version of rgdal from this site :

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html

and installed it :

```
install.packages("filename.tar", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31460497)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me (running R 3.5.1 on Linux Mint 17.1). GDAL version in the Ubuntu repositories is 1.11.3, this causes installation of rGDAL to fail. Here is the solution that worked for me (from [this](https://jgommels.com/2016/09/18/installing-gdal-and-rgdal-on-linux-to-read-kml-files/) website):

```
sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev
```

Download and install GDAL

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.1.1/gdal-2.1.1.tar.gz
tar xvf gdal-2.1.1.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.1.1
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Verify version

```
gdal-config --version
```

I then got this error:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
libgdal.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

This was fixed by updating the bindings:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Then running `install.packages("rgdal")` in R worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to get rgdal to install properly, I have tried all mentioned and all suggestions here  [R not finding package even after package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407092/r-not-finding-package-even-after-package-installation)

```
library(rgdal)
rgdal: version: 1.4-3, (SVN revision 828)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version: 1.3-1 
Warning message:
package ‘rgdal’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

I have upgraded my R to 3.6.1

Try again:

```
batch_gdal_translate(x, desc, outsuffix = "4.img", of = "HFA", co="TILED=YES")
NULL
Warning messages:
1: In gdal_setInstallation() :
No GDAL installation found. Please install 'gdal' before continuing:
    - www.gdal.org (no HDF4 support!)
    - www.trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ (with HDF4 support RECOMMENDED)
    - www.fwtools.maptools.org (with HDF4 support)

2: In gdal_setInstallation() : If you think GDAL is installed, please run:
gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan=FALSE)
```

i have tried to run this from Rstudio & command line R 3.6.1 GUI.

all times I have tried this I get positive results for the libraries being installed.

```
library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
library(rgdal)
rgdal: version: 1.4-4, (SVN revision 833)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version: 1.3-1 
library(gdalUtils)
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'R.oo':
method        from       
throw.default R.methodsS3
```

the files I am trying to read are dted files?

```
x <- list.files(path = src, pattern = ".dt", full.names = TRUE)
length(x)

batch_gdal_translate(x, desc, outsuffix = "4.img", of = "HFA", co="TILED=YES")
```

I have tried the above with GTIFF .tif format also and I get the same error.
But I am not trying to read .hdf files, just .dt0, .dt1, .dt2

this will work on another machine that I have R installed on, however, I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the installation I have on "this" machine.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly adding the include path in CFLAGS worked for me

```
install.packages('rgdal', type = "source", configure.args=c('CFLAGS=-I/apps/proj4/5.2.0/include'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MacPorts` this should work:

1. Install `gdal` (`proj6` will be installed as a dependency)

   ```
   sudo port install gdal
   ```
2. Install `pkg-config`

   ```
   sudo port install pkgconfig
   ```
3. Set `PKG_CONIFG_PATH` variable to point to a directory with `proj.pc` file. In my case this was:

   ```
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/proj6/lib/pkgconfig
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Conda environment please use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-rgdal
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken r-rgdal
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 r-rgdal
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 r-rgdal

conda install -c conda-forge proj
```