# Failed to install package "rgdal"

Tags: r

I use R-studio on a server, I used to install other packages successfully, but when I tried to install the package"rgdal", there are errors:

```
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++ -m64
configure: rgdal: 0.9-1
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 518
configure: gdal-config: gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... 
./configure: line 2119: gdal-config: command not found
no
Error: gdal-config not found
The gdal-config script distributed with GDAL could not be found.
If you have not installed the GDAL libraries, you can
download the source from  http://www.gdal.org/
If you have installed the GDAL libraries, then make sure that
gdal-config is in your path. Try typing gdal-config at a
shell prompt and see if it runs. If not, use:
 --configure-args='--with-gdal-config=/usr/local/bin/gdal-config'
with appropriate values for your installation.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/ruser1/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpDEInGw/downloaded_packages’
```

Based on the errors, I typed gdal-config at shell and command not found. How and where can I install GDAL libraries?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation do you have these libraries installed?

Comment: It's right in front of you:`gdal-config: command not found`.