# RGDAL won't install

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, gdal, rgdal

I can't get RGDAL to install in R. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

```
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/james/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

I found some solutions which said to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev 
sudo aptitude install libproj-dev
```

I follow these through, accepting 'yes' when prompted, but afterwards the same original error. It doesn't resolve it. I wonder whether I should be downgrading something perhaps?

Thanks, James.

Comment: Installing `libgdal-dev` should have fixed it. Are you sure you installed `libgdal-dev` and the error is the same?

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for the response. I have fixed this but I'm not quite sure how to be honest. Basically when I did 'sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev' instead of saying 'yes' to the solution proposed, I said 'no' and it gave me another option, and I said 'yes' to that instead. I think maybe it rolled some of my libraries back to earlier versions perhaps. Anyway, it's working. :-)

Comment: Installing libgdal-dev worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15248953/2641825)  `sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev libproj-dev`

Comment: How to install `libgdal-dev` on mac? I saw Ubuntu or Linux every where, but it seems doesn't work for mac OSX.

Comment: In fact, I have the same problem. In your description, I run sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev as you suggeested. When it runs sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev, it asked me y/n/q, i tried y at first, but did not work. Then I tried n, it worked! Now I have installed rgdal in my R. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rgdal package installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation)

Answer (score 1):

First check that everything is up to date with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

On a slight tangent - i usually also install and a few others (needed for libraries like tidyverse):

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Then install Rgdal and proj.4 (you may have to click yes a few times):

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev 
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev
```