# How to install rgdal and/or upload raster on google-collaboration

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I am trying to upload several rasters on tif format with google-collaboration. However I always had the same error message:

"Cannot create RasterLayer object from this file; perhaps you need to install rgdal first"

So, I tried to install rgdal...and another error appeared:

"Installation of package had non-zero exit status."

I tried to install using a local file, and apparently, its run ok, however, when i required the package, another error appeared:

"Error in library(rgdal) : there is no package called ‘rgdal’

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: 4: 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: 5: 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: 6: package ‘rgdal’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)"

Could anyone help me to fix these errors?

I provide my session info and a fragment of code

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/liblapack.so.3

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] snowfall_1.84-6.1 snow_0.4-3        biomod2_3.3-7.1   ggplot2_3.2.1    
[5] reshape_0.8.8     raster_2.9-23     sp_1.3-1         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gbm_2.1.5             zoo_1.8-6             tidyselect_0.2.5     
 [4] purrr_0.3.2           splines_3.6.1         lattice_0.20-38      
 [7] colorspace_1.4-1      viridisLite_0.3.0     survival_2.44-1.1    
[10] rlang_0.4.0           hexbin_1.27.3         pillar_1.4.2         
[13] glue_1.3.1            withr_2.1.2           RColorBrewer_1.1-2   
[16] plotmo_3.5.5          plyr_1.8.4            mda_0.4-10           
[19] munsell_0.5.0         gtable_0.3.0          codetools_0.2-16     
[22] latticeExtra_0.6-28   class_7.3-15          Rcpp_1.0.2           
[25] scales_1.0.0          plotrix_3.7-6         abind_1.4-5          
[28] gridExtra_2.3         TeachingDemos_2.10    dplyr_0.8.3          
[31] dismo_1.1-4           rasterVis_0.46        grid_3.6.1           
[34] magrittr_1.5          lazyeval_0.2.2        tibble_2.1.3         
[37] PresenceAbsence_1.1.9 randomForest_4.6-14   Formula_1.2-3        
[40] crayon_1.3.4          pkgconfig_2.0.2       MASS_7.3-51.4        
[43] Matrix_1.2-17         pROC_1.15.3           assertthat_0.2.1     
[46] earth_5.1.1           R6_2.4.0              rpart_4.1-15         
[49] nnet_7.3-12           compiler_3.6.1
```

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
%%R
install.packages("rgdal", dependencies=TRUE,repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/') 
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
myExpl.EUR <- stack(list.files("/content/drive/My Drive/Sycios/",pattern=".tif",full.names=TRUE))
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You made an error in installation but provided no code for how you did the installation from local copy. I'm guessing that you don't realize that you need GDAL and some other system resources that are external to R.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342575/rgdal-wont-install?r=SearchResults&s=1|108.3931

Answer (score 2):

Try this from the command line

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev
```

And then in R

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

Comment: I have try this solution, but I got the Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:6: unexpected symbol
1: sudo apt
         ^
Traceback: