# "rgdal" installation failed on ubuntu

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, travis-ci, rgdal

I use travis to check my R package, it's based on a virtual machine of ubuntu. One of my dependencies is `rgdal` from CRAN, which cannot be installed correctly on travis.

First it said:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘rgdal’ is not available for package ‘my package’
```

I followed the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation), then comes the endless dependencies, I installed one by one, according to the instruction of every trial. Finally I installed packages is as below：

```
  libproj-dev
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev
  libdap-dev
  libgdal-dev
  libgdal1h
  libhdf5-dev
  libhdf5-serial-dev
  libgdal-dev
  libgdal1-dev
```

It said I still need to install `libhdf5-7 = 1.8.11-3ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1`

But when I install package `libhdf5-7 = 1.8.11-3ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1`, it gives another error:

```
E: Unable to locate package 
E: Unable to locate package 1.8.11-3ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '1.8.11-3ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1'
```

And it seems no more solutions now.

I wonder how to fix this on travis? Is it a common issue on only travis virtual machine or it could happen on any ubuntu machine? Or the package `rgdal` has some problems with ubuntu?`

**Background**:

All my installation above used `apt-packages` of travis, which is explained as below by travis:

```
apt_packages: A list of packages to install via apt-get. Common examples here include entries in SystemRequirements. This option is ignored on non-linux builds
```

Answer (score 2):

As of this week, you can opt into using Ubuntu 14.04 on Travis:

- See this [blog post from Travis for details](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-11-27-moving-to-a-more-elastic-future)
- See this [.travis.yml](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/blob/master/.travis.yml) where I enable Trusty aka 14.04

Switching to 14.04 may be enough in this case.  If not, also note that you *can* prepare your own .deb packages. I mention this [in an blog post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2015/07/26/#evading_the_hadley_tax_faster_travis_tests) from this summer.

As the geospatial packages are a little involved that is probably your best.  You would need to know how to build Debian packages, and how to use Launchpad to have them auto-built for you.  Both topics have lots of tutorials.

Comment: Thanks very much~I've transferred to the new platform...but it still shows the same information....I am now learning your detailed tutorial on your post. Personally, I am just curious about one point that, as a R package, rgdal should automatically instruct the system to install all the dependencies, why do I still need to install mannually？

Comment: Then you need to rebuild the offending packages so that they fit.  No other way,  sorry.

Comment: As of August 2016 you can specify the Trusty environment (`sudo: required` & `dist: trusty`) and `libhdf5-7` is available and installs