# R: Cannot install package "rgdal" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu-14.04, rgdal

I would like to install the package "rgal" in R. I followed this up: [rgdal package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation). As you can see in the code below, there will be one package removed; unixodbc. This package is quite important. Will I be able to reinstall unixodbc after i removed it? Or is there any other option to install the package "rgdal"?

```
 ~$ sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done

The following extra packages will be installed:
  hdf5-helpers libarmadillo4 libarpack2 libcf0 libdap-dev libdap11
  libdapclient3 libdapserver7 libepsilon1 libfreexl1 libgdal1h libgeos-dev
  libgif-dev libhdf4-0-alt libhdf4-alt-dev libhdf5-7 libhdf5-dev libjasper-dev
  libkml0 libltdl-dev libmysqlclient-dev libnetcdf-dev libnetcdfc++4
  libnetcdfc7 libnetcdff5 libodbc1:i386 libogdi3.2 libpq-dev libpq5 libproj0
  libreadline6:i386 libspatialite-dev libspatialite5 libsqlite3-dev
  libtinfo5:i386 liburiparser1 libwebp-dev libwebpdemux1 libxerces-c-dev
  libxerces-c3.1 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 odbcinst1debian2:i386 proj-bin
  unixodbc:i386 unixodbc-dev uuid-dev

Suggested packages:
  libgdal-doc libhdf4-doc hdf4-tools libnetcdf4 libhdf5-doc libtool-doc
  netcdf-bin netcdf-doc libmyodbc:i386 odbc-postgresql:i386 tdsodbc:i386
  unixodbc-bin:i386 ogdi-bin postgresql-doc-9.3 sqlite3-doc libxerces-c-doc

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  unixodbc

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hdf5-helpers libarmadillo4 libarpack2 libcf0 libdap-dev libdap11
  libdapclient3 libdapserver7 libepsilon1 libfreexl1 libgdal-dev libgdal1h
  libgeos-dev libgif-dev libhdf4-0-alt libhdf4-alt-dev libhdf5-7 libhdf5-dev
  libjasper-dev libkml0 libltdl-dev libmysqlclient-dev libnetcdf-dev
  libnetcdfc++4 libnetcdfc7 libnetcdff5 libodbc1:i386 libogdi3.2 libpq-dev
  libpq5 libproj0 libreadline6:i386 libspatialite-dev libspatialite5
  libsqlite3-dev libtinfo5:i386 liburiparser1 libwebp-dev libwebpdemux1
  libxerces-c-dev libxerces-c3.1 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
  odbcinst1debian2:i386 proj-bin unixodbc:i386 unixodbc-dev uuid-dev

0 upgraded, 48 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 219 kB/24.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 155 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You used `libgdal-dev` but in the link they use`libgdal1-dev`and `libproj-dev`. Perhaps this will not install so much libraries.

Comment: I changed the command to `libgdal1-dev` and `libproj-dev` but this produced the same output. @J_F