# Cannot install rgdal package in R on RHEL6, unable to load shared object rgdal.so

Tags: r, linux, rhel, rhel6, rgdal

I have AWS RHEL6 server where I've installed (compiled) rgdal 1.9.2 and proj packages. Now in R I want to install rgdal package but it gives this error:

> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>   Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
>     unable to load shared object '/home/Roel/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
>     libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted
>   ERROR: loading failed
>   * removing ‘/home/Roel/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgdal’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

Full install log can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/4TDDA7Zk).

When I do locate rgdal.so in Linux it doesn't find anything. I can also not find how to get rgdal.so of what it is part of.

Has anyone any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: read this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation

Comment: Yes, I had this problem before this one but managed to solve it.

Comment: For me the exact error, during install of `rgdal` was `unable to load shared object '/home/<username>/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':` followed by
  `libgdal.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The answer from @RoelEsselink's was the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it:

There is an error further up in the log as well that I had missed because of the error at the end:

```
./proj_conf_test: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libgdal.so.1 was on the system in /usr/local/lib.

I then did:

```
echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/R-dependencies-x86_64.conf
ldconfig
```

This fixed the subsequent error that I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: See the answer from  @user3342735 below if you get permission denied.

Answer (score 4):

If you see Permission Denied when running Roel's, try:

```
sudo ldconfig -c "echo '/usr/local/lib' >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/R-dependencies-x86_64.conf"
```

Comment: Also you may need lib64 not lib.