# rgdal installation error: core dumped when finalizing install

Tags: r, ubuntu, gdal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rgdal

I'm currently using linux subsystem on Windows.
Few days ago I've installed microsoft-r and RStudio and tried to install a `rgdal` package(ultimately I will install `tmap` and `tmaptools` packages). Of course, `libgdal-dev` and its dependencies are correctly configured in the way I've known.

Here's a error message when R finalizes the installation of `rgdal`: *(truncated)*

```
*** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
sh: line 1: 8835 aborted                  (core dumped) '/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.4/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-save --slave 2>&1 < '/tmp/RtmpDpn26L/file1f726636ef3e'
ERROR: loading failed
* removing '/home/felix/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal'
Warning in install packages:
   installation of package 'rgdal' had non-zero exit status
```

`

Does anyone have a similar experience like my case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you `sudo`-start R for the package installation?
This might also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation

Comment: @JanLauGe Sorry I read your comment late. I solved the problem following the link you've suggested. Thank you for your kind response.

Comment: Great to hear, thanks for letting me know :)