# Installing rgdal on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, jupyter-notebook, rgdal

I recently setup a jupyterhub on Ubuntu 16.04. I successfully added R and added most packages I need, but for some reason there are a lot of issues adding the rgdal package. I have followed many other guides online such as the following lines:

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal libgdal1-dev`

As well as:

`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cran.rediris.es/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo apt update`

When I try to run `conda install -c conda-forge r-rgdal` I get the following output and I am not sure what exactly I should do to fix it

`UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - r-microsoftr
  - r-rgdal -> r-base=3.4.1 -> _r-mutex=1[build=anacondar_1]
  - r-rgdal -> r-base=3.4.1 -> pango=1.40 -> harfbuzz=1.3
  - r-rgdal -> r-base=3.4.1 -> tk=8.5`

Here is the output when I try to run install.packages("rgdal") in the jupyterhub:

`** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
configure: CXX: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++
configure: rgdal: 1.3-2
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 755
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ supports C++11 features by default... yes
configure: C++11 support available
checking for gdal-config... /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/jupyterhub-tutorial/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 2.1.4
checking GDAL version >= 1.11.4... yes
checking gdal: linking with --libs only... no
checking gdal: linking with --libs and --dep-libs... yes
checking GDAL: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/jupyterhub-tutorial/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... yes
configure: pkg-config proj exists, will use it
configure: PROJ version: 4.9.2
checking proj_api.h presence and usability... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/jupyterhub-tutorial/lib/R/library/rgdal’
ERROR: dependency ‘rgdal’ is not available for package ‘gdalUtils’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/jupyterhub-tutorial/lib/R/library/gdalUtils’`

EDIT: I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation) and when I enter `apt-file search proj_api.h` I get the same output `libproj-dev: /usr/include/proj_api.h` but I am not sure what I am supposed to do with this to make it work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated - it seems like everything I try will not work. Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my question. I have already been looking at this linked post but it was still not able to fix any problems. I am confused on what the solution to that problem is saying, but I followed it and I am still in the same spot.