# rgdal doesn't recognize GDAL version

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal, rhel6

I'm trying to installed rgdal on RHEL 6. I've install GDAL version 1.7.3 and PROJ version 4.7.0-1. When I run

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

I get the following error:

```
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.7.3
checking GDAL version >= 1.11.4... no
configure: error: upgrade GDAL to 1.11.4 or later
ERROR: configuration failed for package ârgdalâ
* removing â/usr/lib64/R/library/rgdalâ
```

The rgdal [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) says you need GDAL 1.1 or above. Is GDAL 1.7 not supported? Can anyone show me how to install a compatible version of GDAL or explain how to get R to recognize my current version?

I'm using R 3.5.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rgdal package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation)

Answer (score -1):

You need to have at least GDAL version 1.11, not 1.1.