# proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations

Tags: r, linux, centos, r-sf, proj

I am trying to install the `sf` package in a CentOS machine but I keep getting this error

`proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations`

Even though when I run `locate proj_api.h` it is found in `/usr/local/include/proj_api.h`

Comment: Can you include the versions of everything relevant and a transcript of the output from the install?

Comment: You should provide the command you are using to configure things. I am guessing it is an Autotools project. Set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, then run `./configure`. Alternately, if you are compiling and linking, then show your compile and link commands. In this case, add `-I/usr/local/include` to your `CFLAGS`, and add `-L/usr/local/lib` to your `LDFLAGS`. Maybe related, see [rgdal package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15248815/608639)

Comment: Have you tried installing sf from github directly?

Comment: solved it in fedora with `sudo dnf install proj-devel` plus `sqlite-devel` and `geos-devel`

Answer (score 3):

I my case help when I was set PKG_CONFIG_PATH envirmoment, and point them to place where was "proj.pc" file:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: How do you point to the location of "proj.pc" in an installer argument, --with-proj-lib=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/proj.pc ?

Comment: Like I mentioned above, You must set envirnonment variable: PKG_CONFIG_PATH with path to proj.pc in Your system, not in installer argument.

Comment: I did setup PKG_CONFIG_PATH in my env but was not sure about your second step, "point them to place where was "proj.pc" file."

Answer (score 1):

Try this from the command line.  It worked for me when I got the same error message on Mac Mojave:

```
R CMD INSTALL sf_0.7-4.tar.gz --configure-args='-with-gdal-config=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/unix/bin/gdal-config -with-geos-config=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3B/unix/bin/geos-config --with-proj-include=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/include --with-proj-lib=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/unix/lib'
```

You will need to confirm locations of gdal-config, geos-config, include, and lib for PROJ. and your most recent versions for each installation and the .tar.gz file.  I found a similar issue and the answer [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/612)

Answer (score 0):

Recently the configure of `sf` changed a lot with regard to `proj`. Installing the development version from github solved the the failing configure in my case

```
remotes::install_github('r-spatial/sf')
```

Comment: Still getting this error on macoS Catalina, R 3.6.2, even when trying the development version of sf (same with the CRAN release). Reinstalled proj and all dependencies to no avail

```
checking proj.h usability... yes
checking proj.h presence... yes
checking for proj.h... yes
checking PROJ: checking whether PROJ and sqlite3 are available for linking:... no
configure: error: libproj not found in standard or given locations.
```