# Trouble getting latest version of GDAL on ubuntu running R

Tags: r, ubuntu, gdal

My Ubuntu machine has latest GDAL (2.2.1, released 2017/06/23). But R complains that I have gdalversion <2.0

```
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.11.3
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... no
configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0
```

How can I direct R to access GDAL (2.2.1 version) already installed on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 30):

You may need to uninstall all traces of gdal then re-install it from the ubuntugis-unstable source. The following helped me solve a similar problem:

```
sudo apt remove libgdal-dev
sudo apt remove libproj-dev
sudo apt remove gdal-bin
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

Make sure a version >= 2.0 appears when you execute this line:

```
sudo apt-cache policy libgdal-dev
```

If so, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgdal-dev
```

I could then successfully execute in R 3.4.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 ("Trusty Tahr") this:

```
install.packages('rgdal')
```

Comment: I agree with @HugoKoopmans: Should add apt-get update before the apt-cache policy libgdal-dev to make sure it's the required version.

Comment: The stable repository has a gdal 2.1.3 version, so you can add the stable repository instead of the unstable with:
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa

Comment: I had to use the unstable ppa today to install.  Note to self, remove ppa at the command line later using these instructions: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/

Comment: Actually getting a compile error now `/usr/include/projects.h:148:33: error: conflicting types for ‘projUV’`.  Sad.

Comment: Further note to self: Followed previous notes to self here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141422/error-gdal-config-not-found and still had the exact same problems.

Comment: Adding the stable repository version worked for me on Ubuntu trusty 14.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin proj-bin libgdal-dev libproj-dev
```

From: https://gist.github.com/dncgst/111b74066eaea87c92cdc5211949cd1e