# r Rgdal install fails on ubuntu 20.04 with error double red or corruption (!prev)

Tags: r, rgdal

I have a new pc that I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on. I have added R4.0.0 and RStudio 1.2.5042. I need Rgdal and have tried installing it in a variety of ways - directly from CRAN within RStudio, from R in a terminal, and from github. They all fail with similar error messages. Attempting to install sf has a similar failure. It's message is from checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available for running: the sf message is free(): invalid pointer ./configure line 3594:102773 Aborted (core dumped) ./gdal_proj. It appears there is a problem with the gdal installation. gdalinfo --version returns GDAL 3.1.0 and after some usage options. FAILURE: no datasource specified; free(): invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the directions at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289630/trouble-getting-latest-version-of-gdal-on-ubuntu-running-r) solved the rgdal problem. Now have a different, non-gdal error with sf so need to research that.

Answer (score 5):

I installed libspatialite-dev and libgeotiff-dev, and that fixed it.
Credit: https://www.mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg36151.html

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me when I ran into a similar error message installing the sf R package. Specifically, I was trying to update to latest spatial package versions via ubuntu-unstable repository and only updated libgdal-dev, libgeos-dev, and libproj-dev. After updating these packages too, sf succesfully installed.