# Ubuntu 16.04 R Installation: configure: gdal-config not found or not executable

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, gdal, linux-mint

#### System info:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
64 bit
```

I'm trying to install rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz for a research project.  I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141422/error-gdal-config-not-found) and did

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal1i

R CMD INSTALL rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz 
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.2-16
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 701
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal’
```

So then I tried opening R:

```
R
> install.packages('/home/n/Downloads/rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
```

but got

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.2-16
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 701
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal’
Warning message:
In install.packages("/home/n/Downloads/rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz", repos = NULL,  :
  installation of package ‘/home/n/Downloads/rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Please point out where I am missing something

---

More info that may help:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.2-7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3  grid_3.4.3      lattice_0.20-35
```

===============================================

#### Edit:

===============================================

I ran

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

and reran

```
> install.packages('/home/n/Downloads/rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.2-16
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 701
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin//gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.11.3
checking GDAL version >= 1.6.3... yes
checking gdal: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: /usr/share/gdal/1.11/pcs.csv readable... yes
configure: -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/include/gdal
checking proj_api.h presence and usability... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal’
Warning message:
In install.packages("/home/n/Downloads/rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz", repos = NULL,  :
  installation of package ‘/home/n/Downloads/rgdal_1.2-16.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to install `gdal`, `proj` & `geos` on your Linux system.

```
 sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev gdal-bin libproj-dev proj-data proj-bin libgeos-dev
```

To compile yourself, see this [script](https://gist.github.com/robinkraft/2a8ee4dd7e9ee9126030) ([backup](https://pastebin.com/iE4zwQTb))

**Edit:** For Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic or Mint 19 Tara

```
 sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev gdal-bin libproj-dev proj-data proj-bin libgeos-dev
```

Comment: Fixed my problem.  Related/follow-up questions should be asked too to add to this answer