# Install rgdal dependencies on local redhat

Tags: r, redhat, yum, gdal, rgdal

I have to install `rgdal` package on R (this is an other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903905/rgdal-package-had-non-zero-exit-status) I posted before about `rgdal` and this is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which it doesn't work for redhat), So I must install some dependencies before install `rgdal`. if you check the CRAN depo [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) you will notice that GDAL and PROJ.4 are ones of required packages to build `rgdal` from source.

knowing that I'm in linux Os (Redhat 6) and My server is local (not connected to internet only some redhat repositories which don't contain all redhat packages). I downloaded those packages and I used `yum install` to install them:

For example this is what I got when I would install `gdal`:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gdal.x86_64 0:1.8.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcfitsio.so.0()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdap.so.11()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdapclient.so.3()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdapserver.so.7()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgeos_c.so.1()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgeotiff.so.2()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.2()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libodbcinst.so.2()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libogdi.so.3()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librx.so.0()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialite.so.2()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxerces-c-3.0.so()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gdal.x86_64 0:1.8.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcfitsio.so.0()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdap.so.11()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdapclient.so.3()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdapserver.so.7()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgeos_c.so.1()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgeotiff.so.2()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libogdi.so.3()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librx.so.0()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialite.so.2()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.14-14.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6.x86_64
---> Package xerces-c.x86_64 0:3.0.1-20.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gdal.x86_64 0:1.8.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcfitsio.so.0()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdap.so.11()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdapclient.so.3()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdapserver.so.7()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgeos_c.so.1()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgeotiff.so.2()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libogdi.so.3()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librx.so.0()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialite.so.2()(64bit) for package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libgeotiff.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libgeos_c.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: librx.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libcfitsio.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libspatialite.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libdap.so.11()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libogdi.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libdapserver.so.7()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64 (/gdal-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libdapclient.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
lgtoclnt-8.2.3.7-1.x86_64 has missing requires of libcap.so.1()(64bit)
```

every package of those below dependencies needs a similar number of package in his turn. which means I need to install like a 100 of packages manully.

I have been straggling with this problem like 3 days now and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Have done this myself unfortunately - its more like a dozen packages. If you have access to another Red Hat or similar machine that does have internet try https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259640

Comment: have you ever install rgdal before ? if yes, did you install all those packages?

Comment: See also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181048/786542