# rgeos package installation error on linux [R]

Tags: r, linux, rgdal

I'm trying to install the package rgeos on linux. I get the following error:

```
system("sudo apt-get update")
system("sudo apt install libgdal-dev -y")
install.packages("rgeos")
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: Install failure: compilation and/or linkage problems.
configure: error: initGEOS_r not found in libgeos_c.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
```

I have already install the dev libgdal and it returns the "already installed" info if I try to run the sudo again.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181048/

Comment: Same here on ubuntu 16.04 / R 3.5.1 and the solution in the thread linked by Tung didn't help, everything was already installed.

Comment: Looks like it is something specific to 0.4-1 version of rgeos as 0.3-28 is running fine here but update cannot be done because of this issue.

Comment: If it's an archive issue I'll try grabbing rgeos archive from CRAN via devtools::install_version

Comment: @cmbarbu, you are right, it's an issue with the 0.4-1 update from just four days ago. Archive version WORKS:`devtools::install_version("rgeos",version="0.3-28")`

Comment: It's a bug, developer has replied on this thread on the R-sig-geo mailing list. http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Re-Unexpected-configure-error-following-recent-rgeos-release-td7592423.html

Comment: Also a problem in 0.4-2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a bug, you could use this to install lower stable version.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_version("rgeos", version = "0.3-28")
```

After this code all should be fine.