# Installing R `sf` and `RPostgres` packages on Unbuntu 18.04.4

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04, gdal, r-sf, rgdal

Desire is to installed R *{sf}* and *{RPostgres}* packages on Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Trying:

```
R$> install.packages("sf")
```

> configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.

Some SO searching (eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181048/2802810) suggests this:

```
sh$> sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

> The following packagess have unmet dependencies:   libpq-dev :
> Depends: libpq5 (= 10.12-0Ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1 is
> to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have broken
> packages.

I also need `libpq-dev` for R *{RPostgres}*.

Comment: You probably want to upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 and take advantage of the `r-cran-*` on that LTS, as many changes, particularly regards PROJ6-7, and it'`s impact on rgdal, sf & etc.

Comment: Will def move to 20.+ LTR soon as poss.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add PPA, depending on your R version.

[https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u](https://launchpad.net/%7Emarutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u)

[https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u3.5](https://launchpad.net/%7Emarutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u3.5)

[https://launchpad.net/~c2d4u.team/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u4.0+](https://launchpad.net/%7Ec2d4u.team/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u4.0+)

After adding PPA, you can install using `sudo apt install r-cran-sf` and `sudo apt install r-cran-rpostgres`

Comment: Didn't know about these. Look useful.

Answer (score 0):

OKaaaay. The box I'm working in didn't have a Postgres repo installed (https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). Never libpq libs and that was all it needed.

Comment: You'll still want ubuntu 20.04+ to resolve myriad headaches.