# Install spatial packages like terra, sf, raster had non-zero exit status on databricks

Tags: r, databricks, gdal, rgdal, terra

I want to install `terra` package and other spatial packages (`raster`,`sf`) on databricks but running into below issues. On my databricks notebook, I do

```
install.packages("terra")
```

[image]

Based on the error message, the gdal is not configured. I am trying to find resources online that explains to me how to resolve it. I found this page but looks like there are so many solutions but don't know which one to use. Could anyone keep me like a step-to-step guide on how to configure rgdal on databricks and install spatial R packages.

[Error: gdal-config not found while installing R dependent packages whereas gdal is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141422/error-gdal-config-not-found-while-installing-r-dependent-packages-whereas-gdal)

Comment: in a bash terminal, what does `gdalinfo --version` show? Do you have Proj.org and Geos installed as libs?

Comment: Sorry how do I get the bash terminal in databricks? I am on a windows machine

Comment: I did this 
%sh
gdalinfo --version

and I get 

GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this. At this stage, I do not know why this works but running the below commands does the job. In the databricks notebook, I did this

```
%sh # this is to specify you want to run a shell command
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-client 
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev 
sudo apt-get install -y libssl1.1 
sudo apt-get install --allow-downgrades -y libssl1.1=1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev 
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install -y gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install -y libgdal-dev
sudo apt-get install -y python3-gdal
gdal-config
```

Then on the next cell, I did this and it managed to install `terra`

```
%r
install.packages("terra")
```

Answer (score 1):

That suggests that you do not have GDAL installed. You can have a look at the instructions for installing dependencies [for terra](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) and (overlapping, but with more detail) [for sf](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf).

In the comments you say that you are on a "windows machine", but that does not seem entirely accurate. It appears that "databricks" runs on Linux. That is, you are in a Linux environment (that you happens to access from a windows machine). But you may not have access to a terminal.

I do not know databricks, but perhaps [this answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60557852/635245) (it shows how to install GDAL on databricks)

Comment: Okay. Thanks Robert. I am going to follow these instructions. I am not very familiar with linux environment but will try to follow the instructions. Thanks for the prompt response

Comment: Thanks Robert. I did the below and it worked. Posting my solution in case someone else might use data bricks

Answer (score 0):

Have to install some missing clients and gdal using the following.

```
%sh

sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
sudo apt clean && 
sudo apt update --fix-missing -y &&
sudo apt install -y libmysqlclient21
sudo apt install -y gdal-bin

%sh
sudo apt --fix-missing -y update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install -y libudunits2-dev libproj-dev libgeos-dev libgdal-dev
```

And then run `install.packages(c("sf", "terra","raster"))`