# gdal-config not found while installing packages, Mac M1 Ventura

Tags: r, gdal

I am trying to install some packages to work with spatial data such as `sf`, `stars`, `rgdal`, on a Mac Book Air M1 with Ventura. 
To do so, I need to have `gdal` installed to my compute, which I have. My problem is that when I try to install a library (see example with `sf` here below), the gdal-config file is not found.

[image: Example with sf installation]

But I have it on my computer, so my question is : 
Is there a way to indicate the path to R to find that file ?

I tried to to uninstall and reinstall gdal with homebrew, I have proj that is also a dependency rightly installed.
I need to install from sf from sources as it is needed to install the stars package.

```
(base)@MacBook-Air ~ % echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

```
(base)@MacBook-Air ~ % whereis gdal-config
gdal-config: /opt/homebrew/bin/gdal-config /opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/gdal-config.1
```

```
(base)@MacBook-Air ~ % gdal-config
Usage: gdal-config [OPTIONS]
Options:
    [--prefix[=DIR]]
    [--libs]
    [--dep-libs]
    [--cflags]
    [--datadir]
    [--version]
    [--ogr-enabled]
    [--gnm-enabled]
    [--formats]
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  13.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

```
(base)@MacBook-Air ~ % proj
DeprecationWarning: PROJ_LIB environment variable is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release. You are encouraged to set PROJ_DATA instead.
Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
usage: proj [-bdeEfiIlmorsStTvVwW [args]] [+opt[=arg] ...] [file ...]
```

P.S: I know there are a lots of related topics ([Error: gdal-config not found while installing R dependent packages whereas gdal is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141422/error-gdal-config-not-found-while-installing-r-dependent-packages-whereas-gdal)), but all of them are on Linux, and the solutions are not working for me on Mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reinstalling the latest version of R and R Studio.

Comment: Should I delete this post ?

Comment: You don't need to delete your post, as it does solve the problem, though without explanation. Your issue stemmed from the fact that you tried compile the package yourself. This came up, because CRAN does not provide binaries for older R versions. You could have avoided this issue by choosing the older binary version instead of compiling the latest version of the package yourself. Updating R also resolved it, because CRAN does provide the latest package binaries for the latest R versions. Thus, after the update, your were never prompted to compile the package yourself.